# fulltext queries using prefix

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm trying to use ArangoDB to do a fulltext query for names, and I would like to be able to search by initial, e.g. searching for "John J. Doe" or "J. Doe" would both return John James Doe. I set the index `minLength: 1` and I'm trying to use the `prefix` tag for the search, e.g. `"prefix:J,Doe"`. Unfortunately this makes the searches unusably slow (5 seconds for a single search over 1.6M records). Should this be working faster or is it the expected behavior with `prefix:` queries of length 1?

Answer (score 0):

ArangoDB utilises the ICU tokenizer to split words on their boundaries.
You can inpsect its work in arangosh using the `SYS_SPLIT_WORDS_ICU` command:

```
SYS_SPLIT_WORDS_ICU()
usage: SplitWordlist(<value>, minLength, [<maxLength>, [<lowerCase>]])
```

So for your your case you may try to:

```
SYS_SPLIT_WORDS_ICU('John J. Doe', 1)
[ 
  "John", 
  " ", 
  "J", 
  ".", 
  " ", 
  "Doe" 
]
```

which is probably the cause for the high cpu utilization. A minimum length of 3 seems to be a good compromise. 
If you need certain features, you have to prepare a special search field in your application which prepares your text for the index.